# Noms d'animaux où de plantes pour s'adresser à un enfant

Tags: demande-de-mot

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres noms d'animaux pour s'adresser à un enfant avec affection?

Je pense à des expressions comme:

> ma puce, mon chou, ma biche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il en existe toute une ribambelle … tirée d'une véritable ménagerie !

- mon canard, mon poulet, mon biquet, mon poussin, mon chaton, …

Voici une liste qui en fournit d'autre, d'inspirations diverses : [réf.](http://niveaumoyen1.canalblog.com/archives/2016/09/28/34377642.html). La liste est copiée ci-dessous.

Mon ours
Mon nounours
Loulou
Mon lapin
Mon poussin
Mon chou
Mon petit poulet
Mon petit tigre
Mon canard
Mon biquet
Chaton
Mon petit canari
Mon canari des îles

Surnoms amoureux pour filles

Ma puce
Pupuce
Chouchou
Chaton
Ma tourterelle
Bichette
Biquette
Louloute
Ma tigresse
Ma petite fleur
Ma caille
Ma crevette
Ma poulette

En voici d'autres ([réf.](https://tplmoms.com/2019/03/20/les-petits-noms-doux-des-tpl-kids/)).

Ti-pou
tite-puce
tite-punaise
poulets-minou
la belette
bêbête à bajoues
Bébé-poussin
Petit crapaud d'eau douce
rose à petit pois
petit-pois
ma Lapin
Violette-Poulet
Vivi-Poulet
Poupou (?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117106/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-noms-danimaux-ou-de-plantes-pour-adresser-un-enfant).